# Calling subprocess gives error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had written following 2 programs,

```
# TempHello.py
def sayHello():
    print 'Hello World !'
sayHello()

# Subprocess.py
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Calling other program'
    child = subprocess.Popen( "./TempHello.py" , shell=True)
    print subprocess.check_output()
    print 'Calling other program completed'
```

When I try to run the Subprocess.py program, it gives following error as,

```
    Calling other program
    ./TempHello.py: 2: ./TempHello.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/mandar/AnuntaTech/eclipse_workspace/BackupManager/Subprocess.py", line 7, in <module>
        print subprocess.check_output()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
        process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

I am not able to figure out how to solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: Is `TempHello.py` executable? Don't you need a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoachimPileborg, silly mistake from my side. Thanks a lot. Also calling subprocess.Popen('python ./TempHello.py') works equally for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `Popen` is trying to execute `TempHello.py` as if it were a shell executable, when in fact it is a Python script. Simplest solution is fixing `Subprocess.py` like this:

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Calling other program'
    child = subprocess.Popen( "python TempHello.py" , shell=True)
    print subprocess.check_output()
    print 'Calling other program completed'
```

In fact, you'll want to invoke Python executable and make it run your script.

On *nix platforms (thus, not including Windows), you can also use a shebang to specify which interpreter to use, like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
def sayHello():
    print 'Hello World !'
sayHello()
```

Or

```
#! /usr/bin/python
def sayHello():
    print 'Hello World !'
sayHello()
```

and make the script executable with `chmod u+x TempHello.py`.

By the way, **I suggest you to take a different approach in spawning Python scripts**, if that's your purpose: have a look at `multiprocess` module.

Answer (score 2):

You are running TempHello.py as a program. But it is just python source code. 
How about putting this line in the beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and run

```
chmod u+x TempHello.py
```

before running Subprocess.py

Comment: This solution requires a unix-like platform, it will not work on Windows and the like. Apparently, the OP is using Linux, but still he/she cannot consider this solution as being cross platform.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments. But I guess the crux of the problem is pointed out and the question is solved in the simple answer.